# Specific kind of relation in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

For example, I've got a table `A` with structure:

```
int id | int ref_id | varchar name
0            -           hello
1            0           world
```

And entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "mypack.A")
public class A
{
  @Id
  @Column(name = "ID")
  private int id;

  @Column(name = "REF_ID", nullable=true)
  private int ref_id;

  @Column(name = "NAME")
  private String name;
  // getters and setters

}
```

Row with id 1 refers to row with id 0. How can I do this kind of relation using Hibernate? I have an idea to create A class object inside that. Is it ok?

Comment: If one child A only can have a given parent A, it's a OneToOne. If several children A can have a given parent A, it's a ManyToOne. You declare this kind os association the same way you declare an association to another entity.

Comment: Do I have to set `@JoinColumn(name = "REF_ID")` to A object or what?

Comment: Yes, in addition to `@ManyToOne` or `@OneToOne`. Just as you would do for any other such association.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use instead of the property ref_id of type int use a reference to another A object.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "mypack.A")
public class A implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @Column(name = "ID")
  private Long id;
  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "REF_ID")
  private A refA;
  @Column(name = "NAME")
  private String name;
  // getters and setters
}
```